# Arithmetic Progression Time and Work Problem

Tags: arithmetic

> A group of men working at the same rate can finish a job in $45$ hours. However, the men report to work, one at a time, at equal intervals over a period of time. Once on the job, each man stays until the job is finished.
>   If the first man works five times as many hours as the last man, find :
>
> 1) The number of hours the first man works.
>   2) The total number of men in the group.

I know it is an AP problem but I can't figure out how to solve it. I also know I have to use the formula $n = (l-a)/d + 1$
where $l$ = last term, $a$ = first term, $d$ = common difference, $n$ = no. of terms

Comment: Try writing things down explicitly rather than relying on the formula.

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed like that. Can I get some hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that there are $M$ men in the group.  We are told that it takes $45M$ man-hours to finish the job.  Now suppose the first man comes to work at time $0$ and works until time $T,$ and that the other men arrive at intervals of $h$ hours.  The second man arrives at time $h$ and works until time $T$ so he works $T-h$ hours.  The second man arrives at time $2h,$ so he works $T-2h$ hours and so on.

The total number of man-hours worked is $$
T + (T-h)+(T-2h)+\cdots+(T-(M-1)h))=M\left({2T-(M-1)h\over2}\right)=45M$$ so that $$2T-(M-1)h=90\tag{1}$$

The first man works $T$ hours, the last man works $T-(M-1)h$ hours and we are told that $$T=5(T-(M-1)h)$$ so that $$4T=5(M-1)h\tag{2}$$  Solving $(1)$ and $(2)$ simultaneously gives $$\begin{align}
(M-1)h&=60\\
T&=75\end{align}$$

We can say that the first man works $75$ hours (without any rest!) and the last man $15,$ but the number of men is not determined.  If $M=2,$ the first man works $75$ hours, the last man works $15$ and the whole job takes $$75+15=90=45M\text{ man-hours.}$$  If $M=3,$ then $h=30,$ the second man works $45$ hours, and the whole job takes $135$ man-hours.  Any integer $\ge2$ gives a valid value for $M.$

Comment: The answer is given as 61 for the 2nd part.

Comment: @RaphX Do you see a mistake in my answer?

Comment: @RaphX Perhaps here was some information given in the textbook that you didn't transcribe.  Did they tell you at what intervals the men arrive, perhaps?

Comment: Nope, this was an exact copy of the question. The answer for the first part is correct i.e. 75 but for the 2nd one they have given 61 as the answer.

Comment: Well, it appears that is wrong.  You can check the examples I gave yourself.

Comment: Ok, can you please elaborate why each man works until time T?

Comment: @RaphX It says, "Each man stays until the job is finished," and I'm calling the finishing time $T.$

Comment: Got it , thanks!